# iTextSharp "Wrong number of Colums" every Time

Tags: itext

This is my code:

```
base.OnEndPage(pdfwriter, document);
PdfPTable Fusszeile = new PdfPTable(3);
Fusszeile.SetTotalWidth(new float[] { iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate().Width - 25 });

PdfPCell linkeZelle = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("----------------"));
Fusszeile.AddCell(linkeZelle);

PdfPCell mittleZelle = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("--------------"));
Fusszeile.AddCell(mittleZelle);

PdfPCell rechteZelle = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("-------------------"));
Fusszeile.AddCell(rechteZelle);

Fusszeile.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 25, document.Bottom, pdfwriter.DirectContent);
```

I set `3` Colums on Table and I add `3` times a `PdfPCell` and every Time I get the Error `Wrong number of Colums` .

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception isn't thrown because of the number of cells you're adding. The exception is thrown because you aren't defining the column widths correctly:

```
PdfPTable Fusszeile = new PdfPTable(3);
Fusszeile.SetTotalWidth(new float[] { iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate().Width - 25 });
```

If you pass an array to the `SetTotalWidth()` method, the number of elements in that array needs to match the number of columns.

The `SetTotalWidth()` method needs to be used like this if you want to define the total width of the entire table:

```
Fusszeile.SetTotalWidth(PageSize.A4.Rotate().Width - 25);
```

Or like this if you want to define the widths of the different columns:

```
Fusszeile.SetTotalWidth(new float[] { 
     (iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate().Width - 25) / 2,
     (iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate().Width - 25) / 4,
     (iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate().Width - 25) / 4
});
```

Note that I now define the width of **3** columns. The first column takes half the total width, the second and third column take a quarter of the width.

**Important:** Whatever you define as total width is ignored if you don't lock the width.

Comment: the first one is not working but is Need a float ...
the second one works fine ^^

thank you very much (what a fu** error-text ....)

Comment: I'm not that familiar with C#. Do you mean I should cast `25` to a `float`?